# How to rewrite sync method using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui

Now I'm using UIImage sync extension.

```
struct PostView: View {
    let url: String
    
    var body: some View {        
        PrivateImageView(image: UIImage(url:url))
     }
}
```

```
extension UIImage {
    public convenience init(url: String) {
        let url = URL(string: url)
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
            self.init(data: data)!
            return
        } catch let err {
            print("Error : \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }
        self.init()
    }
}
```

When I post a image, I got the error `Synchronous URL loading of http://local.host/images/123.jpeg should not occur on this application's main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness. Please switch to an asynchronous networking API such as URLSession.` at `try Data(contentsOf: url!)`.

In PostView I use `PrivateImageView`.

To use the view I have to designate the argument like this `PrivateImageView(image: UIImage(xxxxxxxxx))`.

I mean I have to use `UIImage()` not `AsyncImage`.

I don't know how to change `convenience init` to adjust to `PrivateImageView`.

Please tell me how to use an async function in this context.

Comment: Use `try await URLSession.shared.data(from:)`, there are plenty of answers here and articles  online for this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54597264/9223839) for instance. But you shouldn't do it in an init though imo but in a function

Comment: I already did like this
```
extension UIImage {
    public convenience init(url: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: url) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
                
                if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.init(data: data)
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
        self.init()
    }
}

```
But it did't work. So I asked this question.

Comment: And I am telling you to use the new async/await function in URLSession

Comment: @Takeshi please [edit] your question with additional code and info. Don’t put it in comments since it is difficult to read.

Comment: With SwiftUI just use AsyncImage instead of UIImage extension: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get a `data` from the inter/intranet synchronously you have to use an `async` method and account for the time it takes to download.

```
extension String {
    public func getUIImage() async throws -> UIImage {
        guard let url = URL(string: self) else {
            throw URLError(.badURL)
        }
        
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
        }
        
        guard httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
            throw URLError(URLError.Code(rawValue: httpResponse.statusCode))
        }
        
        guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
            throw URLError(.fileDoesNotExist)
        }
        return image
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    static public func fromURL(url: String) async throws -> UIImage {
        let image = try await url.getUIImage()
        return image
    }
}
```

You can rewrite `PostView` to something like.

```
struct PostView: View {
    let url: String
    @State private var uiImage: UIImage?
    var body: some View {
        Group{
            if let uiImage {
                PrivateImageView(image: uiImage)
            } else {
                ProgressView() //Show this while downloading
                    .task {
                        do {
                            self.uiImage = try await url.getUIImage()
                            // or
                            // self.uiImage = try await UIImage.fromURL(url: url)
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In fact `PostView` has `let user: User` property. I want to use `use.profileImageUrl` as `url` in this context.  And `use.profileImageUrl` is optional string. What do I  add to your good code?

Comment: @Takeshi you have to unwrap the string somehow, a switch and put a placeholder in “none” and the current code in “some”